# Error in counter variable?

Tags: c++, pearson

I have a quick question about a glitch in this coding.

When I ran this program and it entered this loop (by inputting 1 as the number), everything went smoothly, except that even though I entered `++generalcounter1;` into the body of the loop, it doesn't appear to be adding one to this variable every time the loop plays through. It never runs the message it is supposed to run when the variable == 10.

Please help me I'm very frustrated! Your advice is greatly appreciated!

Sorry if this was unclear, I'm new to this site as well as programming.

```
while (number == 1){
 int addend1;
 int addend2;
 int sum;
 int answer1;
 int generalcounter1 = 0;
 int reply1;

 ++generalcounter1;

 addend1 = 1 + rand() % 50;
 addend2 = 1 + rand() % 50;

 sum = (addend1 + addend2);

 cout << "\nWhat is " << addend1 << " plus " << addend2 << "? ";
 cin >> answer1;

 if (answer1 == sum){
     reply1 = winstatement(); 
 }          
 else{
     reply1 = losestatement();
 }

 if (generalcounter1 == 10){

     if (rightanswers >= 8){
        cout << "\nCongratulations, you are ready to go to the next level!\n" << endl;
     }
     else{
        cout << "\nPlease ask your teacher for extra help.\n" << endl;
     }  
  }   
}
```

Comment: You should **really** try and format your code correctly, as Bob edited. I would never touch code with formatting that poor.

Comment: i guess this line will not be outputted no matter what since rightanswers variable is no declared on other places : cout << "\nCongratulations, you are ready to go to the next level!\n" << endl;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're declaring a new `generalcounter1` each iteration of the loop, incrementing it, and having it be destroyed at the end of the iteration. Move the declaration outside of the loop to have just the one incrementing each time, instead of a new one each time that just gets destroyed before it's ever incremented twice.

```
int generalcounter1 = 0;
while (number == 1) { 
    //loop body
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel like an idiot now. I will quickly change this!

Comment: @user1691432, I remember doing this exact problem. Either the book or my teacher proclaimed bonus for making a timer that counted down so that you had a time limit on answering it. Too bad there's no standard way to do that.

Comment: @SethCarnegie, That was quite a bit before I discovered C++11, but I was talking about a non-blocking input function. I think I used `kbhit`, but the closest thing I can find is the claim that `_getch` is somehow ISO.

Comment: @user1691432 if this answer answered your question, please click the check mark at the top left of it to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @chris oh sorry, I was not in sync with the conversation. Yeah, it sucks we don't have non-blocking IO, hopefully that will get added.